# Indexing: Presenting integer values in a 'n' bit string, turning on bits according to integer value

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers. Each index has `3` values.

`[{24, 17, 22}, {16, 4, 38}, {25, 13, 38}, {32, 18, 15}, {8, 10, 18}]`

I am trying to convert them into `39 bit` string and turning on bits according to `integer` values.

For example, `{24, 17, 22}` means that I should turn on bits `24, 17, 22` among `39 bits`.

**Sample Code:**

```
p1='000000000000000000000000000001011000000' #39 bit just to get length (39)
for x in range(0, len(mylist), 1):
    a = mylist[x]
    a = ''.join('1' if i in a else '0' for i in range(len(p1)))
    print (len(a))
    print (a)
```

**Output:**

```
39
000000000000000001000010100000000000000
39
000010000000000010000000000000000000001
39
000000000000010000000000010000000000001
39
000000000000000100100000000000001000000
39
000000001010000000100000000000000000000
```

if we look at numbers `{16, 4, 38}, {25, 13, 38}` in the list, the last two numbers are `38`. Their `39 bit` ouput string are `000010000000000010000000000000000000001` and `000000000000010000000000010000000000001`. However, the on bits should be at index `38` not `39`.

**Am I making a mistake?**

Comment: Does `for i in range(1, len(p1)+1)` solve it?

Comment: using bits `res = 1<<39` and `res |=  1<<(39-17) | 1<<(39-22) | 1<<(39-24)` then set the left most bit will result into your required binary string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you bit indices start at 1, but the string indices start at 0. You could check for `i+1 in a` to shift them all left by one:

```
mylist=[{16, 4, 38}]
p1='000000000000000000000000000001011000000'
for x in range(0, len(mylist), 1):
    a = mylist[x]
    a = ''.join('1' if i+1 in a else '0' for i in range(len(p1)))
    print (len(a))
    print (a)
```

Outputs:

```
000100000000000100000000000000000000010
```

with bit 38 now activated instead of bit 39